# Extend function with Doctrine ORM Annotation

Tags: zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got the following situation: a (Doctrine Entity) ContentCategory that is extending the DataObject class. The DataObject class has the following function, onPrePersist:

```
/**
*  @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class DataObject implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
 ...
 /** @ORM\PrePersist */
 public function onPrePersist()
 {
     //using Doctrine DateTime here
     $this->creation_date = new \DateTime('now');
 }
```

The ContentCategory class needs this function aswell. When I put this function in the ContentCategory class it works just fine. Is there a way whereby, the ContentCategory class can use the same function, onPrePersist() without defining it in the class itsself?

```
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class ContentCategory extends DataObject implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
 ...
}
```

The reason to give objects the onPrePersist function, is to set a DateTime when this object is created or any other object / entity that is extending the DataObject class.

--< Edited >--

I've currently added a construct method to the ContentCategory like this:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::onPrePersist();
}
```

In this way Doctrine executes the function onPersist when a new Entity is created. The other case is when an enttiy is being updated, with Doctrine. I'll like to set a Modified_date. In that case there will be a function like this, in the DataObject class.

```
/**
*  @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class DataObject implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
 ...
/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function onUpdate()
{
    $this->last_modified_date = new \DateTime('now');
}
```

The Doctrine ORM Annotation (PreUpdate) that have been added, will make sure that the function (above) will be excuted on an update statement for an object. The problem is, how to call those functions in an object which extends the DataObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class TestimonialSuperclass
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PreFlush
     */
    public function onPreFlush ()
    {
        echo 123;
    }
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="testimonials")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Testimonial extends TestimonialSuperclass
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt knew about the Doctrine ORM Annotation: MappedSuperclass. With this annotation it doesn't make an Entity for the Super(parent)class. Thanks alot, for opening my eyes!